# Multiple Sphinx Themes Used Simultaneously

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to use multiple themes in Sphinx - so that one page has one theme, and a second page has a second theme.  It seems to me that only one theme can be set at once - is this true?

Many thanks,
Ned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, only one Sphinx theme can be used at a time.